# Posted ViewModel is always NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, null, viewmodel

My ViewModel always returns `null` and don't know why. Can someone look at my code and check what is wrong here and why my filled model with data from view returns to controller as `null`?

```
public class PaintballWorkerCreateViewModel
{
    public PaintballWorker PaintballWorker { get; set; }
    public PaintballWorkerHourlyRate HourlyRate { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    PaintballWorkerCreateViewModel model = new PaintballWorkerCreateViewModel()
    {
        PaintballWorker = new PaintballWorker(),
        HourlyRate = new PaintballWorkerHourlyRate()
        {
            Date = DateTime.Now
        }
    };
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
[PreventSpam(DelayRequest = 20)]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PaintballWorkerCreateViewModel paintballWorker)
{
    (...)
}
```

View, even added HiddenFor IDs (which aren't created in `GET` function in controller).

```
@model WerehouseProject.ViewModels.PaintballWorkerCreateViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Utwórz pracownika";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout_Paintball.cshtml";
}

<h2>Dodawanie pracownika</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "PaintballWorkers", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PaintballWorker.Active)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PaintballWorker.MoneyGot)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.PaintballWorker.PaintballWorkerID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HourlyRate.Date)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HourlyRate.PaintballWorkerID)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.HourlyRate.PWHourlyRateID)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaintballWorker.Imie, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.PaintballWorker.Imie, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.PaintballWorker.Imie, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.PaintballWorker.Nazwisko, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })

(...)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.HourlyRate.HourlyRate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.HourlyRate.HourlyRate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @type = "number", @min = "0.1", @step = "0.1", @value = "10" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.HourlyRate.HourlyRate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Dodaj pracownika" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Powrót do listy", "Index", new object { }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
</div>
```

Comment: Is it all values are null or only a few values?

Comment: `PaintballWorker` and `HourlyRate` are null, even if I create model and fill it with data in `GET` function.

Comment: Can you show the code for the 2 classes?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/CN5KmBqF

Comment: Did you say even the GET function is null? Does the view not get populated with those values?

Comment: I mean I create model in `GET` function and it's ok, my values are passed to view, but posted back to controller values are `null`

Comment: Change the name  of the parameter in your  POST method to anything other than the name of a property and it will work fine

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine.. looks like it's reference is being lost somewhere.. have you tried to remove the `[PreventSpam(DelayRequest = 20)]` attribute? So your controller would be like this:

```
public ActionResult Create()
    {
            PaintballWorkerCreateViewModel model = new PaintballWorkerCreateViewModel()
            {
                PaintballWorker = new PaintballWorker(),
                HourlyRate = new PaintballWorkerHourlyRate()
                {
                    Date = DateTime.Now
                }
            };
            return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(PaintballWorkerCreateViewModel paintballWorker)
    {
        (...)
    }
```

Comment: No, removing `PreventSpam` didnt help

Answer (score 0):

You are not posting the form correctly. Since the attributes are hidden, they are null by default.

After posting your controller does not see anything since the elements are hidden. Therefore it is null.

Use the extension method @Html.TextboxFor instead. Mvc viewengine will render the textbox and then you can put some values and post them.

you also need to make sure that you have mapped the route correctly in your code.

Comment: No, that's not a problem, I've changed `HiddenFor` to `EditorFor` and still both are `null`

Answer (score 0):

your problem may be because of naming conflict, that is the parameter name of the post action may not be the same as the property name in your viewmodel

Kindly follow the below link:

https://forums.asp.net/t/1670962.aspx?ViewModel+in+post+action+is+null

In that it specified solution and route cause for the problem clearly.

Note : I also had the same problem long back and solved it in the same way as mentioned. Hope it will be useful for you too

thanks

Karthik